# geth eth_protocolVersion is returning error : "the method eth_protocolVersion does not exist/is not available"

Tags: blockchain, geth

i am using stable geth.

```
geth 
version Geth Version: 1.10.7-stable
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16.6 
Operating System: darwin 
GOPATH= GOROOT=go
```

i am having issues with calling the eth_protocolVersion :
postman error ==> "error": {
"code": -32601,
"message": "the method eth_protocolVersion does not exist/is not available"
}

i attached the geth console and printed all eth functions, where i am getting "protocolVersion: undefined"

i tried with building the geth of current master branch, getting the same issues.

INIT genesis file by :

```
geth --identity "dappslab" --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api txpool,admin,eth,net,web3,personal --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins "*" --ws.api txpool,admin,eth,net,web3,personal --graphql --graphql.corsdomain "*" --datadir /Users/$(whoami)/DappsChain/node1 --port 30303 --networkid 13936 init /Users/$(whoami)/DappsChain/Genesis.json
```

running geth by :

```
geth --identity "dappslab" --syncmode full --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api miner,txpool,admin,eth,net,web3,personal --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins "*" --ws.api miner,txpool,admin,eth,net,web3,personal --graphql --graphql.corsdomain "*" --datadir /Users/$(whoami)/DappsChain/node1 --port 30303 console
```

I have googled this issue but i can't find any solution for this.
Am i doing this wrong or the geth have bug or removed this function?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

The method was removed in Geth v1.10. See their [blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/03/geth-v1-10-0/) where the mention it.

> Note, the eth_protocolVersion API call is gone as it made no sense. If you have a very good reason as to why it’s needed, please reach out to discuss it.